# How to create typings for extended object with dynamic property

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to create typings for an object with additional dynamic property.

**Heres what I tried.**

```
interface Entity {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface NestedEntity {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const getNestedObject = () => {
  return {
    id: "1",
    name: "test1",
  }
}

const expand = <T>(obj: Entity, path: string): Entity & { [path]: T } => {
  const nested = getNestedObject() as any;

  return {
    ...obj,
    [path]: nested,
  }
}

const entity: Entity = {
  id: "1",
  name: "test1",
}

const obj = expand<NestedEntity>(entity, "nested");
obj.nested // should be visible.
```

I think `Entity & { [path]: T }` result is too naive and its should be done different way.

How to get around this?

Cheers

Comment: I think you can keep it, don't see any issue here.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm try to put this code into TS playground. You will see that TS does not allow this code `obj.nested`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add overloading:

```js
interface Entity {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface NestedEntity {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const getNestedObject = () => {
  return {
    id: "1",
    name: "test1",
  }
}

function expand<Obj, Path extends string>(obj: Obj, path: Path): Obj & Record<Path, ReturnType<typeof getNestedObject>>
function expand<Obj, Path extends string>(obj: Obj, path: Path) {
  const nested = getNestedObject();

  return {
    ...obj,
    [path]: nested,
  }
}

const entity: Entity = {
  id: "1",
  name: "test1",
}

const obj = expand(entity, "nested");
obj.nested // should be visible.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGWWABMAuZAZzClAHMBuQ5EOAWwgutpEfwF98%20UJFiIUAOQjUIJdGEw4CRUlxr0mRVhzU8%20g-AgD2IasjoQwUmSQDyAIwBWEBGGQBeZAAoAlB4B8eMxQlgCuUCBBRCrkyABEAIxxADTMWuyc8ZDUSalEggYwoSCuwCbIEAAeAA5wICQAPA6OycgACnBgABYVlZD1lFTqvP5eRk4Uza213RQd3T6TTsgAZMgASi5GUI3zXa2bYOEgACpY1RAN2BdGMOaW1pB2Ti5g-v74RSUK5VW19U0nK09r1%20iRBtx6KNxo4li1kDMunNOl0-MpkMZTG4QNInh57lZcbJmq9fExgmEIlFogA6OkwvLRADaiIAuhQcTZGQUhJizBAMNgKPJFPj0ap4rlmNpMnFsmApQY%20W4Yfi-nUSF4BQpsK04pynnEfEwYTSDbJkAB6S1ULpGUIAGxIyHsKAAbsBKMB7A6IDSgA)

Please keep in mind, if you use computed property like `{ [path]:... }` TS does not treat is as `Record<path, any>`.